# How to compare two array items in associative array and assign new value

Tags: php

I am trying to assign primary and secondary static key => value into an associative array based on two conditions.

I have an array like this,

```
$testarray = array(
array(
    array(
        'id' => 'ccdbh-743748',
        'name' => 'test',
        'email' => 'testemail@test.com',
        'newsletter' => 'abc',
        'created_at' => '1546753453'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 'uisvuiacsiodciosd',
        'name' => 'test',
        'email' => 'testemail@test.com',
        'newsletter' => 'def',
        'created_at' => '1546753453'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 'sdcisodjcosjdocij',
        'name' => 'test',
        'email' => 'testemail@test.com',
        'newsletter' => 'ghi',
        'created_at' => '1546753453'
    )
),
array(
    array(
        'id' => 'sdcisodjcosjdocij',
        'name' => 'test',
        'email' => 'testemail@test.com',
        'newsletter' => 'abc',
        'created_at' => '1546753453'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 'ccdbh-743748',
        'name' => 'test',
        'email' => 'testemail@test.com',
        'newsletter' => 'def',
        'created_at' => '1546753453'
    )
),
array(
    array(
        'id' => 'sdcisodjcosjdocij',
        'name' => 'test',
        'email' => 'testemail@test.com'
        'newsletter' => 'abc',
        'created_at' => '1546753453'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 'sdcisodjcoscisudhiu',
        'name' => 'test',
        'email' => 'testemail@test.com'
        'newsletter' => 'def',
        'created_at' => '1515217453'
    )
)
```

);

The first condition would be against this ID ccdbh-743748, if we found any matching ID then this must be the primary one, and others will be secondary then.
But if there is no ccdbh-743748 found in the array item, then we need to check with the created_at field whichever is older gets the primary value and the remaining will get the secondary attribute.

I have tried this code so far, but I am not sure at this stage how created_at will going to work in this code.

```
$data = [];
              
foreach( $testarray as $main_items ){
    $newitem=[];
    foreach ($main_items as $sub_item) {
        $p = ($sub_item['id']==='ccdbh-743748') ? 'primary' : 'secondary';
        $sub_item['profile_type']=$p;
        $newitem[]=$sub_item;
    }
    $data[]=$newitem;
}

print_r($data);
```

At this point, if the array contains ccdbh-743748, it will set primary to that item and others will get secondary value.
Do I need to run another loop to check if no array item contains a primary value then does it's mean it should be calculated with the create_at field?
Is there a way that we can use array_search with array_column in the existing loop, or is there any better approach to do this?

The final results that I am looking for are like this.

```
$finalarray = array(
    array(
        array(
            'id' => 'ccdbh-743748',
            'name' => 'test',
            'email' => 'testemail@test.com',
            'newsletter' => 'abc,def,ghi',
            'created_at' => '1546753453',
            'profile_type' => 'primary'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'uisvuiacsiodciosd',
            'name' => 'test',
            'email' => 'testemail@test.com',
            'newsletter' => 'def',
            'created_at' => '1546753453',
            'profile_type' => 'secondary'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'sdcisodjcosjdocij',
            'name' => 'test',
            'email' => 'testemail@test.com',
            'newsletter' => 'ghi',
            'created_at' => '1546753453',
            'profile_type' => 'secondary'
        )
    ),
    array(
        array(
            'id' => 'sdcisodjcosjdocij',
            'name' => 'test',
            'email' => 'testemail@test.com',
            'newsletter' => 'abc',
            'created_at' => '1546753453',
            'profile_type' => 'secondary'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'ccdbh-743748',
            'name' => 'test',
            'email' => 'testemail@test.com',
            'newsletter' => 'abc,def',
            'created_at' => '1546753453',
            'profile_type' => 'primary'
        )
    ),
    array(
        array(
            'id' => 'sdcisodjcosjdocij',
            'name' => 'test',
            'email' => 'testemail@test.com',
            'newsletter' => 'abc',
            'created_at' => '1546753453',
            'profile_type' => 'secondary'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'sdcisodjcoscisudhiu',
            'name' => 'test',
            'email' => 'testemail@test.com',
            'newsletter' => 'abc,def',
            'created_at' => '1515217453',
            'profile_type' => 'primary'
        )
    )
);
```

Thanks

Comment: I do not see the difference between arrays or the logic

Comment: @GiacomoM The final array contains profile_type in each array item,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this example, made taking into account past wishes for the style of the code and changes in the original question, can help you.

```
const SPECIAL_KEY = 'ccdbh-743748';
const NEWS_LETTER_DELIMETER = ',';

$total = array_map(
    function($item) {
        $primaryIndex = null;
        $newsLetters = []; 
        array_walk(
            $item,
            function(&$subItem, $index) use (&$item, &$primaryIndex, &$newsLetters) {
                $subItem['profile_type'] = 'secondary';
                $newsLetters = array_merge($newsLetters, explode(NEWS_LETTER_DELIMETER, $subItem['newsletter']));
                if (!is_null($primaryIndex) && $item[$primaryIndex]['id'] === SPECIAL_KEY) return false;
                if (is_null($primaryIndex)
                    || $subItem['id'] === SPECIAL_KEY
                    || intval($item[$primaryIndex]['created_at']) >= intval($subItem['created_at'])) {
                    $primaryIndex = $index;
                }
            }
        );

        $newsLetters = array_unique(array_map('trim', $newsLetters)); // cleaning and normalization of the array
        if (!is_null($primaryIndex)) {
            $item[$primaryIndex]['profile_type'] = 'primary';
            $item[$primaryIndex]['newsletter'] = implode(NEWS_LETTER_DELIMETER, $newsLetters);
        };
        
        return $item;
    },
    $testarray
);

print_r($total);
```

[Working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b51bec8507aa48a7a921f7d8da29b48d160c0f37)

Comment: Isn't there any precise example, like more concise or robust solution for this,
Can we not use array_searh with array_column or probably by using array_filter to achieve this ?

Comment: @BilalAhmed, I have updated the example to a short version, and also added an example in a different style (which is more comfortable for you).

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
I have tried your solution and it is working fine. One last thing that I want to fix in this array, I have edited my question and final array. I need to merge or combine all newsletter item values into primary array item with comma separated values.
Do you have any preferred solution for this.

Comment: @BilalAhmed, I updated the sample code (based on a functional solution) in the response and removed the old code examples from the response.

Answer (score 0):

Your nested loop approach is exactly what I would use.  The fine detail is in determining if a given row qualifies as the group's primary row.

1. If there is no cached primary candidate in the group, then use the current row; or
2. if the current row's id is assigned special significance, use the current row; or
3. if the current's id is NOT special and the cached row's id is NOT special and the current row's `created_at` value is less than the cached row's `created_at` value; then cache the row's index as the best candidate in the group as the primary row.

Beyond that, keep pushing the group's `newsletter` values into an array while looping.

When the loop finishes, update the winning candidate's data with a "primary" `profile_type` value and implode all of the group's newsletter values to update the `newsletter` value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QGerH))

```
define('PRIMARY_ID', 'ccdbh-743748');

foreach ($testarray as &$group) {
    $primaryCandidateId = null;
    $newsletters = [];
    foreach ($group as $i => &$row) {
        $row['profile_type'] = 'secondary';
        if (
            $primaryCandidateId === null
            || 
            $row['id'] === PRIMARY_ID
            || (
                !in_array(PRIMARY_ID, [$row['id'], $group[$primaryCandidateId]['id']])
                && $row['created_at'] < $group[$primaryCandidateId]['created_at']
            )
        ) {
            $primaryCandidateId = $i;
        }
        $newsletters[] = $row['newsletter'];
    }
    $group[$primaryCandidateId]['profile_type'] = 'primary';
    $group[$primaryCandidateId]['newsletter'] = implode(',', $newsletters);
}
var_export($testarray);
```